# How to save the delimiter?

Tags: javascript, regex

Been attempting this for a while now, wondering how to split a string such as this:

```
"(point_granularity > 5 && point_latitude < 10) || (point > 100)"
```

into this:

```
["(", "point_granularity", ">", "5" .....]
```

My current approach has what I want except instead of the above, it replaces the parenthesis with `""` : `["", "point_granularity", ">", "5" ...]`

I would like to keep the parenthesis, I've looked at other threads however have not been able to accomplish the task.  My current delimiter is:  `/\(|\)|\s/`

I separate at spaces, but don't know what to do for the parenthesis.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why not use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Comment: I use eval() in my current implementation, however I'm using different parts of the string under eval() (and the full string as well).  Picture a venn diagram, I'm grabbing all the information I need for that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  If you know anything about regex feel free to let me know what directions to take!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.split()` supports regex, and matching word boundaries `\b` accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
"(point_granularity > 5 && point_latitude < 10) || (point > 100)".split(/\b/)
```

resulting in:

```
0:"("
1:"point_granularity"
2:" > "
3:"5"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = src.split(/(\(|\s+|\))/);
```

Example:

```
src = "(point_granularity > 5 && point_latitude < 10) || (point > 100)";

result = src.split(/(\(|\s+|\))/).filter( w => w.trim().length > 0);
console.log(result);
```

It should extract data as desired.

```
[ '(',
  'point_granularity',
  '>',
  '5',
  '&&',
  'point_latitude',
  '<',
  '10',
  ')',
  '||',
  '(',
  'point',
  '>',
  '100',
  ')' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
s = '(point_granularity > 5 && point_latitude < 10) || (point > 100)'

console.log( s.split(/\s+|\b/) )
```